# Fullcalendar doesn't scoll to Current Date in timelineWeek view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have purchased the Fullcalendar license.But i'm facing issue as it doesn't scroll automatically to current date in timelineWeek,timelineMonth view.I have attached below the code snipet which I have tried.

```html
if $('#eventcalendarsub').length > 0
  $('#eventcalendarsub,#eventcalendarsubbig').fullCalendar
   scrollTime: moment().subtract(3, 'h')
   disableDragging:true
   nowIndicator:true
   editable: false
   height: 390
   header:
    left: 'today prev,next'
    center: 'title'
    right: 'timelineDay,timelineWeek,timelineMonth'
   defaultView: 'timelineDay'
   resourceLabelText: 'ABC/XYZ'
   resources:
    url: '/ABC.json'
    error: ->
     alert 'There was an error while fetching events!'
     return
   events:
    url: '/XYZ.json'
    error: ->
     alert 'There was an error while fetching resources!'
     return
```

so please help us to achieve this functionality.

Comment: The scrollTime option is listed as an "agenda" option. This means it only works on agenda style Views, and not on others such as timeline. Unfortunately AFAIK there is no way to do what you want. The only thing you could do would be to make the visible range in your view smaller using the other options such as visibleRange, so that the time you want is always the earliest time on the view. Or you could submit a feature request on the project's GitHub page asking for this functionality.

Comment: thanks for the info...but you mean its not possible for timelineWeek view.Any other way we can achieve this??? so that if current time is 2pm then it must stop at 4 Oct at 2pm.

Comment: i have tried many way but its only working with agenda view.I have also used this,but its only working for timelineDay.

Comment: $('#eventcalendarmain').fullCalendar 'gotoDate',moment().add(5, 'days').format('MM/DD/YYYY')

Comment: yes I meant it's not possible for any timeline (or other non-agenda) view using scrollTime. Like I said, you need to make a feature request to the maintainer, or modify the Scheduler source code yourself.

Comment: do you have any example how may i get this??? so dat i can refer your code for example.

Comment: No. Did you not read what I said? This _isn't possible_ using the existing version of fullCalendar. No code currently exists to do this. You need to make a feature request to the maintainer, or modify the Scheduler source code yourself, if you can't wait that long.

Comment: Instructions can be found here already: https://fullcalendar.io/support/ - read the "Feature request" instructions at the link provided, before you do anything.

Comment: is it possible to achieve this functionality using visibleRange????? for example i may set visibleRange of timelineWeek view to start from current date.I dont know how to write this...??

Comment: its current syntax is $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agenda',
    visibleRange: {
        start: '2017-03-22',
        end: '2017-03-25'
    }
});

Comment: i ewant it to work with timelineWeek

Comment: It won't work with timelineWeek, but it will work with a generic timeline view. I was wrong, you _can_ use scrollTime in a timeline view, but only to set the time, not the date. Therefore, to scroll to the current time, the timeline needs to start on the current date as well. The only way to achieve that is using visibleRange. e.g. `defaultView: "timeline",
  visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
   return {
    start: currentDate.clone().startOf("day"),
    end: currentDate.clone().add(3, 'days').startOf("day")
   };
  },scrollTime: moment().format("HH:mm")
`

Comment: is it possible to create an event by selection using timelineDay view...??????   coz im also facing problem in this........!!!!!!!!

Comment: Yes I believe so. But you should ask a new question if you have a different question, and show your code for handling the selection.