# Automatic Scrolling to current date in timelineWeek view using fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using Rails 4 and fullCalendar and want to achieve the following functionality:

Use timelineWeek view to automatically scroll my "now" indicator to the current datetime. I have all my Resources on my Y-axis. I'm having a problem in achieving this functionality with timelineWeek view. Can anyone help?

I have tried the following code for it, but no progress:

```
var firstHour = new Date().getUTCHours() - 5;
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  firstHour: firstHour;
});
```

And also used this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ // Timeout
    $(".fc-today").attr("id","scrollTo"); // Set an ID for the current day..
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollTo").offset().top // Scroll to this ID
    }, 2000);
}, 500);
```

and this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('today');
```

The above code works perfectly for agendaWeek view. The only problem is for timelineWeek view.

Comment: The above code works perfectly for agendaWeek view,only problem is for timelineWeek view.

Comment: do you have any idea about my question???  @ADyson

Comment: AFAIK what you're asking for is impossible, unfortunately. In fact looking back through the scheduler tag, it seems we have discussed this before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558125/fullcalendar-doesnt-scoll-to-current-date-in-timelineweek-view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fullcalendar doesn't scoll to Current Date in timelineWeek view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558125/fullcalendar-doesnt-scoll-to-current-date-in-timelineweek-view)

Comment: ya i know we have discussed this....but can't find any solution by dat...dats why asked the qstn...i'm newbie to fullcalendar....so can't do any hack...so if u have any idea please hlp with some examples.....it will be very nice....as its very important for me....tnxx for ur rply....!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @ADyson  pls have a look...!!!!

Comment: defaultView: "timeline", visibleRange: function(currentDate) { return { start: currentDate.clone().startOf("day"), end: currentDate.clone().add(3, 'days').startOf("day") }; },scrollTime: moment().format("HH:mm")

Comment: this code works perfectly for timelineWeek view...only problem is dat in timelineWeek view week must always start with monday....but the help of above code its not starting......!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: above code is disturbing my firstday monday code....i have written this for it firstDay: 1

Comment: its making my firstDay to start from thursday till next wednesday if today is thursday.

Comment: When we discussed it previously I explained that the solution does not exist. If you re-read it, you'll recall that I explained that  you can use scrollTime in a timeline view, but only to set the time, _not the date_.  The code in your comment above changes the view to start on the current day (because that is the only way, as I explained, in a timeline view, to go to the current day automatically). So naturally it overrides the firstDay setting. That's its purpose. It's a workaround, not a solution, because the solution doesn't exist unless you re-write the fullCalendar source code yourself.

Comment: Anyway the other question is still un-answered (because as was previously explained to you there is no answer) so I don't understand why you asked another one??

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to do this, maybe it is possible to do some other way.

I decided to put scrolling in [viewRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/) function, since it is called on both initial load and changing dates.

Now firstly I check if current time is in my view and we have slot width set.
Then calculate how many slots until the current slot and calculate left scroll. Modify it by your needs: e.g. I wanted to have it to show yesterday on load at far left.

```
if (moment().isBetween(view.start, view.end) && view.timeGrid.slotWidth !== undefined) {
    var scrollSlots = moment.duration(moment() - view.start) / moment.duration(view.viewSpec.overrides.slotDuration);
    var slotWidth = view.timeGrid.slotWidth;
    var scroll = {left: scrollSlots * slotWidth - $('.fc-time-area').width() / 4};
    view.addScroll(scroll);
}
```

End result: on load (cropped out resources). This is month view with 200 [slotWidth](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline/slotWidth/). [image]

Comment: tnx for anss...will check it..!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using React, but I think that you can apply the same solution:

1. Put className to nowIndicator, using the following prop:

nowIndicatorClassNames="fc-now-indicator"

2. Select the element and use the "scrollIntoViewAPI":

document.querySelector(".fc-now-indicator")?.scrollIntoView({block: "center"});

In react the solution would be something like that:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
  document.querySelector(".fc-now-indicator")?.scrollIntoView({block: "center"});
},[])

return( 
  <FullCalendar {...props} nowIndicatorClassNames="fc-now-indicator" />
)
```